# Cleaning Database with Advanced Logics

Tags: excel, database, vba

I have an enormous Excel numeric database to clean. It is an export from Qualtrics (online survey tool) with around 6,000 columns. My aim is to remove values from cells that should be empty basing on logics set I have prepared. 
For example: Values from question #7 should be removed if in question #6 we have response A or B.

I have also a file that is an export of logics which looks like so:

```
Q6.10
If Q6.1#3 = 1 [ 1 ]
Or Q6.2#3 = 2 [ 1 ]
Or Q6.2#1 = 9 [ 1 ]
```

**Meaning:**

Remove values from Q6.10
If following conditions are false:

```
Q6.1#3 = 1 [ 1 ] (in Q6.1#3 1 is at least once selected) 
Or Q6.2#3 = 2 [ 1 ] (or in Q6.2#3 2 is at least once selected)
Or Q6.2#1 = 9 [ 1 ] (or in 6.2#1 9 is at least once selected)
Q6.1 and Q6.2 are multiple choice matrix question.
```

or

```
Q14.24
If Q14.1 = 1
Or Q14.1 = 4
Or Q14.1 = 5
Or Q14.1 = 7
```

**Meaning:**

Remove values from Q14.24
If following conditions are false:

```
   Q14.1 = 1
Or Q14.1 = 4
Or Q14.1 = 5
Or Q14.1 = 7
```

Q14.1 is single choice question.

This is how the part of the database looks like:

[image]

I started creating my own macro which is supposed to remove values from cells where the logic is false and color them red:

```
Public Sub exampleFunction()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim text As String
    Dim textline As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim obj As New Dictionary
    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Open myFile For Input As #1
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        If Left(textline, 1) = "Q" Then
            x = textline
            obj.Add textline, y
        End If
        If trim(textline & vbnullstring) <> vbnullstring AND Left(textline, 1) <> "Q" Then
            obj.Item(x) = obj.Item(x) & " " & textline
        End If
    Loop
    Close #1
    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In obj.Keys
        Dim c As Integer
        With Sheets(1).Range("A1:E65536")
            Set c = .Find(element, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With
    Next element
End Sub
```

What I managed to do with that code:

- opening the file with logics
- creating and object with property: the question ID (of cleaned question) and value: set of logics which are strings

I am not able to find the column (or columns if needed) basing on the property of the object (question ID). Once I find the column(s) I would like to check if the logic from object is true for each row. If the logic is false I would like to check whether there are any values in cells and if they are I would like to color those cells red and remove the values.

I am fluent with JS but VBA is quite new to me.

Comment: It would be easier to just translate your "logics" in to VBA and use it natively. Trying to open and parse logic from a text file is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Agree with @HackSlash - you are just adding an extra layer of complication: whatever you write in your text file could more easily be written directly in VBA.  Unless you didn't write that file and it's coming from another system?

Comment: @HackSlash and Tim thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately in my team we need to use external file but I think I am able to modify the file for easier translation to VBA. My problem is how to use objects (dictionaries/collections) to loop through all around 700 logics (logics are dependent on each other so the number of them is not fixed for each case), find a proper column and clean the row.

Comment: This is not one clean question. You are asking how to approach something which is opinion based. You're not likely to get a good answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "..basing on logics set I have prepared." <-- you know exactly what to do to the data, great. | My inquiry : which column contains what data? | (using that answer..) Use the 'columnListing', generate the if statements as needed. | should you had all those 700 logic done in this format.. you may use `CHOOSE()` or `IF()`. to call it. ( :